# How to print data in table form

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables one is teacher having fields (*teacher_id,name and address*)
and another one is enroll having fields (*enroll_id, student_id, teacher_id and status*) now I just want to print data in table like this

```
teacher_name1   teacher_name2   teacher_name3
student_id       student_id      student_id
student_id       student_id      student_id
```

simply it's mean that every student will be print below it's teacher,how to create this table through `for loop` or through `foreach`??

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question as it is is far too broad to be answerable, so please post some code and let us know what isn't working and we can try to help.

Comment: i just want to echo data from these two tables in the above table form

Comment: Have you joined your table?